# Proper way of passing in a entity (form) to a controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, controller, action

I was writing up a controller action that creates a new user. Currently, the controller action takes in the ***user entity model*** as a parameter.

I was wondering if I should pass values from the front-end in its own ***view model***, and then extract values and create the entity in the backend?

```
public ActionResult AddUser(User user)
{
  context.Users.Add(user);
  context.SaveChanges();
}
```

vs

```
public ActionResult AddUser(UserViewModel userViewModel)
{
  var user = new User(userViewModel.Name);
  context.User.Add(user);
  context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with most things, there are multiple ways to do it.  Ultimately in this case it often comes down to personal preference.

When I'm doing this same thing, I often ask myself if what's being passed into the method is actually a valid `User` at all.  I like to keep my models in such a way that they internally prevent invalid states, rather than rely on the calling code to maintain validity of the model.

As such, sometimes there are actions which receive information which *describes* a model but doesn't fully *construct* a model by itself.  In these cases, I prefer to use a view model.  This often leads me to use view models across the board if for no other reason than consistency.

It particularly comes in handy if I need information from more than one model on the page.  Having a view model that's a composite of the information I need rather than something like a `Tuple` of two models just feels cleaner to me.  This also allows me to add additional properties to the view model (calculated fields, flags, etc.) that are useful to the view but would pollute the business object.  (Switches to show/hide certain form elements, validation items, etc.)

Often times you can find your own preference to this sort of question by noting the difference between an *object* (`User`) and a *data structure* (`UserViewModel`).  In a traditional object-oriented sense, the `User` should hide its data members and provide an interface of functionality, whereas a flat data structure like `UserViewModel` would expose its data members and have no meaningful functionality.

Since the view is just looking to bind to data members, I usually go with a flat view model instead of a domain object.

Answer (score 1):

The academic way would be to create an extra viewmodel class which exposes just the data you need to display or the fields the user needs to enter information for and map them to your domain model as in your second example.

But for small apps or when you need all fields in your model, i think its absolutely ok to pass a domain model object to the view.

Another important thing to consider is security/validation. When using the implicit mvc mapping mechanism and a full domain model, a bad user could send values to your controller you don't want store in your db.
Using a separate view model class involves an explicit mapping step, where you have to tell the system explicitly which field from the viewmodel (= user entered data) you want to map to your domain model.